# C++ Functor as an output argument of a function

Tags: c++, functor

I want to write a function in c++ that takes a variable of type int and what it does is that it will define the overloading operator () of a functor and will return that functor as output argument. For example:

```
template<class Functor>
Functor myFunc(double n)
{
   Functor f; 
   double Functor::operator() (double q) 
   { return n*q;} 
   return Functor; 
} 
class myClass 
{ 
  double operator() ( double q ) const ;
};
```

Is this proper the way of doing it ?

Comment: You cannot define the `::operator()` in other functions [Function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator)

Comment: @rsy56640 When you write a so-called lambda expression, an anonymous class is defined with `operator()` in its public area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a syntactic sugar for what you're trying to do (wrongly). It's called [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and this is what it should look like:

```
auto myFunc(double n)
{
    return [n](double q) { return n * q; }
}
```

If C++11 is not available, you can emulate it like this (which fixes your errors above):

```
class Functor
{
    double m_n;

public:
    Functor(double n) : m_n(n) {}

    double operator()(double q) const { return m_n * q; }
};

Functor myFunc(double n)
{
    return Functor(n);
}
```

If you wish, you can keep `myFunc` as a template, but the point is, you can change the behaviour by the functor you pass in, so trying to hardcode `operator()` inside `myFunc` does not really make sense, and is not possible.

---

Making it more generic:

```
template <typename T>
class Functor
{
    T m_n;

public:
    Functor(T n) : m_n(n) {}

    T operator()(T q) const { return m_n * q; }
};

template <template <typename> class Functor, typename T>
auto myFunc(T n)
{
    // we can use perfect forwarding here, but it's far beyond the original question
    return Functor<T>(n);
}
```

Usage:

```
myFunc<Functor>(2)(3)
```

---

Even more generic, for variable amount of parameters captured by a functor (variadic templates):

```
template <template <typename ...> class Functor, typename ... Ts>
auto myFunc(Ts ... ns)
{
    return Functor<Ts...>(ns...);
}
```